# Как определить расстояние от одного города до другого?

Tags: php

Как определить расстояние от одного города до другого? Может есть какой-то API у яндекса, или гугла?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть ли такие функции в API Яндекса или Гугла - понятия не имею, но это расстояние вполне можно вычислить и самому. Для этого надо знать широту и долготу первого города и широту-долготу второго. Координаты городов можете получить из сервисов Яндекса/Гугла, с этим, думаю, проблем не будет. А формула расчета расстояний выглядит так:

```
L = R * acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1 - lon2))
```

где lat1 - широта первого города в радианах,
    lat2 - широта второго города в радианах,
    lon1 - долгота первого города в радианах,
    lon2 - долгота второго города в радианах,
    R - радиус Земли

З.Ы. При вычислении синусов/косинусов градусы, скорее всего, нужно будет перевести в радианы.

Comment: спасибо, понял))